# Print values from JSON search in PHP

Tags: php, json

I don't know if i'm doing anything wrong or I'm really a dumb. Theres a thing, I'm trying to search a movie in TMDB by this title (in portuguese) and this realease year. I have something like that:

```
$url_call2 = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=7c7506d9bd7e1738bb2af1d29a87fd36&language=pt-BR&query=Corrente%20do%20Mal%20&page=1&include_adult=false&primary_release_year=2014';
$get_contents2 = file_get_contents( $url_call2 ); 
$call2 = json_decode($get_contents2);
```

JSON result is

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "results": [
    {
      "poster_path": "/26PPOZKf6Smk9SdXc4m9B9u4kYm.jpg",
      "adult": false,
      "overview": "A jovem Jay (Maika Monroe) leva uma vida tranquila entre escola, paqueras e passeios no lago. Após uma transa, o garoto com quem passou a noite explica que ele carregava no corpo uma força maligna, transmissível às pessoas apenas pelo sexo. Enquanto vive o dilema de carregar a sina ou passá-la adiante, a jovem começa a ser perseguida por figuras estranhas que tentam matá-la e não são vistas por mais ninguém.",
      "release_date": "2014-08-27",
      "genre_ids": [
        53,
        27
      ],
      "id": 270303,
      "original_title": "It Follows",
      "original_language": "en",
      "title": "Corrente do Mal",
      "backdrop_path": "/nwQgcgGVrKyjlxNzaDZud82pUly.jpg",
      "popularity": 3.744171,
      "vote_count": 1043,
      "video": false,
      "vote_average": 6.7
    }
  ],
  "total_results": 1,
  "total_pages": 1
}
```

So, to print my results i was trying this:

```
echo $call2['results']['title'];
```

Nothing :(

In another exemple, I use a IMDB id and works fine because is not a search, is a exact match. Can anyone help me?

---

None of the sugestions work, and I don't know why :( But I fixed by doing a foreach:

```
$i = 0;
    foreach($call2->results as $i => $values)
    { if ($i == 1) { break; }
      $background = $values->backdrop_path;
    }
```

Works enough. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: you are decoding to a stdClass, yet using as an associative array. Try `$call2 = json_decode($json_getcontents2,true);` . The second parameter defaults to false (stdClass). Also, `results` is an array, you need to have logic to select the appropriate one.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg  I already tried this, nothing as well. I have another code from this database and works without the "true" but when I put, no works. Here's the code: `$url_call = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' .$imdb. '?api_key=' .$api_key. '&language=pt-BR';
 $get_contents = file_get_contents( $url_call ); 
 $call = json_decode($get_contents);
 $tmdb_id = $call->id;
 $background = $call->backdrop_path;`

Answer (score 2):

Add true parameter to json_decode - then $call retun array

```
$call2 = json_decode($get_contents2, true);
```

If you want to select your result use: 
`$call2['results'][0]['title'];`

For future, You can checking structure of the all results by `<pre><?php print_r($call2);?></pre>`

Comment: I tried that already, nothing as well. If i try  `<pre><?php print_r($call2);?></pre>` nothing returns.

Comment: `<pre><?php
$url_call2 = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=7c7506d9bd7e1738bb2af1d29a87fd36&language=pt-BR&query=Corrente%20do%20Mal%20&page=1&include_adult=false&primary_release_year=2014';
$get_contents2 = file_get_contents( $url_call2 );
$call2 = json_decode($get_contents2, true);
print_r($call2);` - it works for me...

Comment: Add die(); after print_r, maybe do you have some other errors

Comment: Nothing :( Can be anything disable in php for my server?

Comment: If i try `var_dump ($call2);` returns NULL.

I have another code to consult this database

`$url_call = 'https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/' .$imdb. '?api_key=' .$api_key. '&language=pt-BR';
$get_contents = file_get_contents( $url_call ); 
$call = json_decode($get_contents);
$tmdb_id = $call->id;
$background = $call->backdrop_path;`

And this works just fine. I don't understand :/

Comment: If it returns null check json_last_error() (see php.net docu on json_last_error for possible error values)

Comment: I fixed doing a foreach `$i = 0;
 foreach($call2->results as $i => $values)
 { if ($i == 1) { break; }
   $background = $values->backdrop_path;
 }` tks guys.